# Python Instagram API - How to cycle through access tokens upon hitting rate limit?

Tags: python, api, loops, instagram, access-token

I have a question regarding Instagram API and rate limits - and how to cycle through access tokens to counter this.

Previously, I built-up an API interface using a statistical software program to pull the data and manually parse. This was before I realized how much easier the Python-Instagram package was.

PROBLEM: That being said, I was able to create a loop where upon hitting a rate limit, it would release the current access token and cycle through a list of access tokens until it hit one with unused requests, and then continue on through the extraction. I'm using this to pull a list of followers for a given user, with this user having over 1 million followers. With the Python Instagram API interface, I'm having troubles re-creating this.

Here's the starting code (from [python-instagram](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram)):

TO EXHAUSTIVELY EXTRACT A LIST OF FOLLOWERS FOR A GIVEN USER:

```
user_followers, next_ = api.user_followed_by(userid) #request data from API
    while next_:
    more_user_followers, next_ = api.user_followed_by(with_next_url=next_) #extract the list of followers
    user_followers.extend(more_user_followers) #append each page of followers into this list with each iteration
```

And here's my attempt at creating a cycle of access tokens until an unused one is hit:

```
counter=0 #set seed counter

user_followers, next_ = api.user_followed_by(userid) #request data from API
    while next_:
        try:
            more_user_followers, next_ = api.user_followed_by(with_next_url=next_) #extract the list of followers and capture any error codes
        except InstagramAPIError:
            counter=counter+1 #upon rate-limit error, increment counter by 1 to call each access token
            if counter==1:
                access_token="accesstoken1"
            if counter==2:
                access_token="accesstoken2"
            # etc...
                counter=0 #for the final access_token in the list, reset counter to 0 to re-start at the top of the list and cycle until a hit is found
            api=InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token,client_secret=client_secret) #I think this should push the new access_token to the Instagram API constructor, but perhaps this is where the error lies...
            continue #I think this will break the current cycle and restart under the `while next_:` statement, thus attempting to pull the data using the new access token
        user_followers.extend(more_user_followers) #append each page of followers into this list with each iteration
```

The rate limit error is successfully captured with the `try:` statement, and the loop will cycle through the access tokens correctly - but for some reason, these do not get recognized or "pushed" back to the Instagram API interface and the data does not get pulled. The loop just keeps cycling through codes.

I know this is possible because I've done it by manually requesting the endpoints and switching access tokens upon hitting a rate limit error (using another software package), but I would like to do this with the `Python` Instagram API.

My initial thoughts are that the `continue` break does not reset the loop at the appropriate upstream point, or that the access tokens cannot be "switched out" within a given call to the `user_followers, next_ = api.user_followed_by(userid)` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution - take all tokens randomly.
Statistically load will be spreaded nearly equal after many runs.

If suddenly one of them gets exhausted - take next.

```
    import random
    tokens = ['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'cccc', ...]
    token = random.choice(tokens)
```

Comment: Excellent, this piece of coding simplifies the access token cycling and spreads out the usage! Great to learn something new.